# Searching for a row based on the grouping of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Preface, I am not sure the question even make sense.

### Problem Statement

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----------------+-----------+
| ProductGroupID | ProductID |
+----------------+-----------+
|              1 |         1 |
|              1 |         2 |
|              2 |         3 |
|              2 |         4 |
|              3 |         1 |
|              3 |         2 |
|              4 |         1 |
|              4 |         2 |
|              4 |         3 |
+----------------+-----------+
```

What I am trying to do is find all `ProductGroupID`s that contain both `ProductID` 1 and 2.

### Desired Output

```
+----------------+
| ProductGroupID |
+----------------+
|              1 |
|              3 |
|              4 |
+----------------+
```

### My Attempt

Below is a naïve script that I created, but I think that it could be vastly improved.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductGroupID
FROM
    (SELECT ProductGroupID FROM tbl WHERE ProductID = 1 ) t1 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ProductGroupID FROM tbl WHERE ProductID = 2 ) t2
ON t1.ProductGroupID = t2.ProductGroupID
```

For some reason, my gut tells me that a `CROSS APPLY` could be useful in this situation, but I cannot seem to reason about the problem.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

### Addendum

Bonus points if you can produce a script that shows `ProductGroupID`s where only 1 and 3 are displayed, and 4 is ignored because it has an extra item in the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `HAVING`:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,1),
                 (1,2),
                 (2,3),
                 (2,4),
                 (3,1),
                 (3,2),
                 (4,1),
                 (4,2),
                 (4,3)) V(ProductGroupID, ProductID))
SELECT ProductGroupID
FROM VTE
GROUP BY ProductGroupID
HAVING COUNT(CASE ProductID WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) >0
   AND COUNT(CASE ProductID WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) >0;
```

If you want to ignore `ProductIDGroup` 4 then:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,1),
                 (1,2),
                 (2,3),
                 (2,4),
                 (3,1),
                 (3,2),
                 (4,1),
                 (4,2),
                 (4,3)) V(ProductGroupID, ProductID))
SELECT ProductGroupID
FROM VTE
GROUP BY ProductGroupID
HAVING COUNT(CASE ProductID WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) >0
   AND COUNT(CASE ProductID WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) >0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN ProductID NOT IN (1,2) THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. Must admit today I learned that you can perform a `GROUP BY` without specifying an aggregation function in the `SELECT` clause!